# Flutter The name FutureOr isn't a type, so it can't be used in an as expression

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

While upgrading the flutter project to null-safety it has appeared the following error

```
    The name 'FutureOr' isn't a type, so it can't be used in an 'as' expression.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing type, or creating a type with the name 'FutureOr'
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like import is missing `import 'dart:async';`

FutureOr is part of `dart:async`